# WebSocket Server that feeds messages to clients in a round robin fashion

Tags: go, websocket

I have a websocket server in Go using the Gorilla websocket package. At this stage, I will have only one server serving 5 clients. I am getting some messages from upstream into the WebSocket server. My intention is to NOT BROADCAST all the messages to the connected clients. I would like to send only one copy of the message to the connected clients in a round robin fashion. It doesn't matter which client gets it as long as there is only one that gets it.

**My attempted solution**
I have a simple Go server, created a Pool of clients (websocket connections) that I am receiving. However, I do not see any options to round robin the messages as I mentioned above. All my clients are getting the message. How can I send only one copy of the message to the connected clients instead of broadcasting to all.

**Discalimer**
The code I have is taken from online sources and modified to my requirement. I am relatively new to Go and Websockets. **Is this something even possible using Websockets?**

### main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/realtime-chat-go-react/backend/pkg/websocket"
)

func serveWs(pool *websocket.Pool, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("WebSocket Endpoint Hit")
    conn, err := websocket.Upgrade(w, r)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "%+v\n", err)
    }

    client := &websocket.Client{
        Conn: conn,
        Pool: pool,
    }

    pool.Register <- client
    client.Read()
}

func setupRoutes() {
    pool := websocket.NewPool()
    go pool.Start()

    http.HandleFunc("/ws", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        serveWs(pool, w, r)
    })
}

func main() {
    setupRoutes()
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080",nil)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

### websocket.go

```
package websocket

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
)

var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{
    ReadBufferSize:  1024,
    WriteBufferSize: 1024,
}

var wsList []*websocket.Conn

func Upgrade(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (*websocket.Conn, error) {
    upgrader.CheckOrigin = func(r *http.Request) bool { return true }
    conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    wsList = append(wsList, conn) //Creating a list here to store all websocket clients.

    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return nil, err
    }

    return conn, nil
}
```

### pool.go

```
package websocket

import "fmt"

type Pool struct {
    Register   chan *Client
    Unregister chan *Client
    Clients    map[*Client]bool
    Broadcast  chan Message
}

func NewPool() *Pool {
    return &Pool{
        Register:   make(chan *Client),
        Unregister: make(chan *Client),
        Clients:    make(map[*Client]bool),
        Broadcast:  make(chan Message),
    }
}

func (pool *Pool) Start() {
    for {
        select {
        case client := <-pool.Register:
            pool.Clients[client] = true
            fmt.Println("Size of Connection Pool: ", len(pool.Clients))
            for client, _ := range pool.Clients {
                fmt.Println(client)
                client.Conn.WriteJSON(Message{Type: 1, Body: "New User Joined..."})
            }
            break
        case client := <-pool.Unregister:
            delete(pool.Clients, client)
            fmt.Println("Size of Connection Pool: ", len(pool.Clients))
            for client, _ := range pool.Clients {
                client.Conn.WriteJSON(Message{Type: 1, Body: "User Disconnected..."})
            }
            break
        case message := <-pool.Broadcast:     //This is where I need to modify the code but not sure how
            fmt.Println("Sending message to all clients in Pool")
            for client, _ := range pool.Clients {
                if err := client.Conn.WriteJSON(message); err != nil {
                    fmt.Println(err)
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### client.go

```
package websocket

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "sync"

    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
)

type Client struct {
    ID   string
    Conn *websocket.Conn
    Pool *Pool
    mu   sync.Mutex
}

type Message struct {
    Type int    `json:"type"`
    Body string `json:"body"`
}

func (c *Client) Read() {
    defer func() {
        c.Pool.Unregister <- c
        c.Conn.Close()
    }()

    for {
        messageType, p, err := c.Conn.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            return
        }

        message := Message{Type: messageType, Body: string(p)}
        c.Pool.Broadcast <- message
        fmt.Printf("Message Received: %+v\n", message)

    }
}
```

Comment: It broadcasts to all clients because that's exactly what you wrote it to do. If you want it to do something else, do that instead. What have you tried, what specifically is your question about how to do this?

Comment: @Nick  You omitted the client send channel and write pump when copying from the Gorilla chat example.  The Gorilla chat example uses the channel and pump to ensure that the server does not block on a slow or dead client.

Comment: @Adrian It obviously broadcasts as per the code. I showed you the code to help me explain how can I change that broadcast to round robin. Not sure why my original question has a negative point on it. All I asked is can I through WebSockets do a round robin instead of a Boradcast. I presented the code that was used for Broadcast as well.

Comment: @Nick Yes, I did copy this from the Gorilla chat example. However, I was trying to refactor this code to round robin instead of broadcast, which you did help me in getting through. My real request is to get a high throughput of Kafka messages from upstream on to my Websocket server and then spray(push) these messages to the connected clients in a round robin fashion so that a message is delivered to only one client, doesn't matter which one. I am relatively new to Go and hence trying to go through the code so that I can better understand what needs to be done.

Answer (score 2):

Modify the pool to store clients in a slice instead of a map.  Add field to record index of the previous client used.

```
type Pool struct {
    Register   chan *Client
    Unregister chan *Client
    Clients    []*Client
    Broadcast  chan Message
    PrevClientIndex int
}
```

Round robin instead of broadcasting:

```
case message := <-pool.Broadcast: 
    if len(pool.Clients) == 0 {
        continue
    }
    pool.PrevClientIndex++
    if pool.PrevClientIndex >= len(pool.Clients) {
       pool.PrevClientIndex = 0
    }
    client := pool.Clients[pool.PrevClientIndex]
    if err := client.Conn.WriteJSON(message); err != nil {
        // handle error
        ...
```

Register appends to the slice:

```
case client := <-pool.Register:
    pool.Clients = append(pool.Clients, client)
    ...
```

Unregister removes the client from the slice:

```
case client := <-pool.Unregister:
    j := 0
    for _, c := range pool.Clients {
       if c != client {
          c.Clients[j] = c
          j++
       }
    }
    pool.Clients = pool.Clients[:j]
    ...
```

Comment: Wow! A lot to digest here. Let me go through this and come back if I have any questions. Thanks a lot for the detailed answer

Comment: I am getting compilation errors due to the conversion of the Clients from map to slice. I am sure I am goofing something up.
````type Pool struct {
 Register        chan *Client
 Unregister      chan *Client
 Clients         []*Client
 Broadcast       chan Message
 PrevClientIndex int
}

func NewPool() *Pool {
 return &Pool{
  Register:   make(chan *Client),
  Unregister: make(chan *Client),
  Clients:    make([]*Client), <---- giving an error here
  Broadcast: make(chan Message),
 }
}````

Comment: I did add Clients:    make([]*Client, 50). But that just limits me to 50 connections which is OK for now but not scalable.

Comment: @Nick This answer gives an overall sketch of the changes required to support round-robin. You will need to work out the small details on your own, including fixing basic Go errors such as the one in your comment.

Comment: Will do. The original solution does help. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: `make([]*Client, 50)` creates a slice with 50 nil *Client values. [Read about slices in the Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/7).

Comment: This gives me a ni pointer deference error
````case message := <-pool.Broadcast:
   fmt.Println("Sending messages tp clients in Round Robin fashion")
   if pool.PrevClientIndex >= len(pool.Clients) {
    pool.PrevClientIndex = 0
   }
   fmt.Println(message)
   client := pool.Clients[pool.PrevClientIndex]````
The value of client is <nil>, hence this error

Comment: I found the issue. I missed incrementing the PrevClientIndex, which kept returning me the 0th value of the int type. Hence, I was getting a nil deference error. I changed the slice as well. The code compiles well but the round robin of the messages didn't work. I am looking further.